# Rounded corners on div used as portal to larger div - rendering bug or my error?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, rounded-corners

I have a div that is deliberately smaller than its content (I'm making a sliding toggle widget). I want the container to have rounded corners. In FireFox, it renders as intended, but Chrome and Safari both show the inner content in the region between where the rounded corners are and where square corners would be.
I can't put rounded corners on the inner content as there is no solution that is right for all scenarios (toggle left, toggle right, toggle in motion).
Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
        <title>DIV test</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-size               : 3em;
            }
            #frame {
                border                  : thin solid black;
                /* background: #a0a0ff; */
            }
            #portal {
                background              : none;
                margin                  : 20px;
                display                 : inline-block;

                -moz-border-radius      : 29px;
                -webkit-border-radius   : 29px;
                -khtml-border-radius    : 29px;
                border-radius           : 29px;
                border                  : thin solid black;

                width                   : 400px;
                overflow                : hidden;
                height                  : 4em;
                line-height             : 4em;
            }
            #inner {
                position                : relative;
                width                   : 900px;
                background              : #a0ffa0;
                z-index                 : -100;
                margin-left             : -150px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="frame">
            <div id="portal">
                <div id="inner">Here are some partially visible words</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this a rendering bug in WebKit browsers, or am I doing something wrong and getting lucky with FireFox?

Comment: Your css formatting is rather unusual. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's a bug, but it sucks.
However, try this fix:
http://jsfiddle.net/tpe36/1/

Works in Chrome and Firefox for me.

HTML:

```
<div id="frame">
    <div id="portal">
        <div id="container">                
            <div id="inner">Here are some partially visible words</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#inner {
    position                : relative;
    width                   : 900px;
    z-index                 : 1;
    margin-left             : -150px;
}
#container {
    background              : #a0ffa0;
}
​
```

Comment: Well, I don't understand why that should make a difference, but it certainly does, thanks. Fingers crossed that it translates to the more complicated real code.

Comment: The difference is that `#container` has the same width as `#portal`. `#inner` has no background-color, so you don't see that its corners are not rounded.

Comment: After a little more thought, I don't think this will translate - the effect I'm striving for is very reliant on the colouring of the inner content (three differently styled spans) that I move around via margin-left on their parent. Styling a container that doesn't move (and matches the size of 'portal') isn't going to have the intended effect. You have certainly answered the question as presented though.

Comment: Putting a sufficiently thick border on #frame of the same colour as the background and a z of -1 on #inner allows me to style the inner content as I'd like and the border obscures the unwanted rectangular protrusions.

Comment: oh. maybe use an image as a wrapper? take a look at that:
http://jsfiddle.net/tpe36/5/

it's not perfect at all, the image is quick-and-dirty. but the idea should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The widget I'm building is configurable/flexible in it's width though, so I don't want to go down the road of using an image (or multiple images). The wide border solution is least intrusive (until I find the next drawback!).